# Python Client for Google Cloud Storage and large files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/), there is no hard limits on file sizes but when I try to upload 100MB files, it fails without any error logs on [administration](https://console.developers.google.com) portal. Has anyone see this before? What's the best way to upload large files (100MB+ < 2GB) on app engine?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states the following:

> Incoming Bandwidth:
> The amount of data received by the application from requests. Each incoming HTTP request can be no larger than 32MB.

This includes:

> Data received by the application in secure requests and non-secure requests
>
> Uploads to the Blobstore
>
> Data received in response to HTTP requests by the URL fetch service

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I assume it is better to use [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview) for large files? If I'm understanding this correctly. There is no library or code that integrates and provide convenience methods?